# Tips on a Stored procedure with CONVERT , Split functions

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dbo

I'm studying a stored procedure with the following variable that I need to decipher, ResponseRange :

```
**@ResponseRange VARCHAR(64) = null,**
```

then later we have:

```
IF (@ResponseRange is not null)
BEGIN
    INSERT 
    INTO #tempLK_ResponseStatuses
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, val) FROM dbo.Split(@ResponseRange, ',')    
END

IF (@ClientResponseRange is not null)
BEGIN
    INSERT 
    INTO #tempClientLK_ResponseStatuses
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, val) FROM dbo.Split(@ClientResponseRange, ',')  
END
```

What is happening with the line

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, val) FROM dbo.Split(....)
```

I believe all the above corresponds to the code from the Web-page CS file, of which here's  a sample:

```
new ResponseGroup() {
        ID = (int) ResponseStatusGroups.Completes,
        Code = 1,
        Label = "Completes",
        ResponseCodes = null,
        ClientResponseCodes = "10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19"
    },
    new ResponseGroup() {
        ID = (int) ResponseStatusGroups.OverQuota,
        Code = 2,
        Label = "Over Quota",
        ResponseCodes = "40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49",
        ClientResponseCodes = "40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49"
```

Comment: what's your best guess?  you have a 'val', a 'convert' and an 'int'(integer)...Also, a quick search would answer your question...

Comment: @MitchWheat - I know it's probably doing converting, a little confused at why it's splitting. is that for if we enter smth like "30, 50 ,70" ?

Comment: you are asking us to to determine why a csv list of values is used.?Because that's the logic being used!

Comment: @MitchWheat - OK i'm starting to understand it. a lot of times I just need to see my code on stackOverflow and study it in my own question .  so thanks/!!